Multihead Attention for 4-D tensor in Pytorch
I tried to transform tensorflow to pytorch, but I have a trouble with multi head attention due to its dimensions.
Input tensors for mha is 4-D, but pytorch mha couldn't accept 4-D tensor as an input for mha.
The shape of tensors is like this:
tmp_page_embed:  torch.Size([64, 16, 1, 256])  
offset_embed:  torch.Size([64, 16, 100, 256]) 

The original tensorflow source code is as below:
tmp_page_embed = tf.reshape(page_embed, shape=(-1, self.sequence_length, 1, self.page_embed_size))
offset_embed = tf.reshape(offset_embed, shape=(-1, self.sequence_length, self.offset_embed_size // self.page_embed_size, self.page_embed_size)) 
offset_embed = tf.reshape(self.mha(tmp_page_embed, offset_embed, training=training), shape=(-1, self.sequence_length, self.page_embed_size))

This is my attempt to covert this as pytorch.
offset_embed = tf.reshape(self.mha(tmp_page_embed, offset_embed, training=training), shape=(-1, self.sequence_length, self.page_embed_size))
tmp_offset_embed, _ = self.mha(tmp_page_embed, offset_embed, offset_embed)
offset_embed = tmp_offset_embed.reshape(-1, self.sequence_length, self.page_embed_size)

The error message is as below:
AssertionError: query should be unbatched 2D or batched 3D tensor but received 4-D query tensor     

How should I fix this error? Is there any way to convert 4D tensor to 3D?

The MHA implementation is specific for 3D inputs. If it makes sense for your input, you can reshape the tensor to 3D. Although most likely mixing axes like that doesn't make sense and you'll need to re-implement MHA for 4D inputs
